# Gray Vertical Lines in Google Maps Web

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps

Hi we noticed that our website was experimenting some issues with our contact map, sudenly some gray vertical lines have appeared. We didn't move anything related to the css or js of the map area so we don't understand what the problem may be.

Here's a screenshot of the area:

[image]

Here's a copy of the html of the area:

```
    <section id=contact>
      <div class=container id=map></div>
    </section>
```

Here's a copy of the script of the map

```
<script>$(document).ready(function(){$("#map").gMap({
  controls:{panControl: false,
  zoomControl: false,
  mapTypeControl: false,
  scaleControl: false,
  streetViewControl: false,
  overviewMapControl: false,
  scrollwheel:false,
  draggable:false},
 markers:[{latitude:19.428058,longitude:-99.161335,icon:{image:"img/pin2.png",iconsize:[32,47],iconanchor:[32,47],infowindowanchor:[12,0]}}],
  icon:{image:"img/pin2.png",iconsize:[26,46],iconanchor:[12,46],infowindowanchor:[12,0]},
  latitude:19.428058,
  longitude:-99.161335,
  zoom:17});});</script>
```

Version og google maps

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>
```

id map css

```
#map{height:300px;width:100%;position:relative;}
```

class container css   (bootstrap.css)

```
.container,
.navbar-static-top .container,
.navbar-fixed-top .container,
.navbar-fixed-bottom .container{width:940px;}
.container{margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto;*zoom:1;}
.container:before,
.container:after{display:table;content:"";line-height:0;}
.container:after{clear:both;}
.container-fluid{padding-right:20px;padding-left:20px;*zoom:1;}
.container-fluid:before,
.container-fluid:after{display:table;content:"";line-height:0;}
.container-fluid:after{clear:both;}
```

Contact section has no css

And here's the link to our website [pixzelle.mx](http://pixzelle.mx)

Please any help will be appreciated

Comment: What does you CSS look like?  Most probably a CSS rule being applied to the map tiles.

Comment: http://pixzelle.mx/css/bootstrap.css Line 38: `img{max-width:70%;}` , you've tried to fix it in line 39 but you use a wrong selector(the id of the map is `map` not `map_canvas`)

Comment: Excellent this worked for me, I didn't found that answer when I was looking but it helps. Thanks a lot